# ASP.NET MVC @Html.PagedListPager add validation before calling action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a grid using `PagedListPager` like this:

```
<div style="float:left;width:70%;margin-left:10%" id="contentPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.SearchResultViewPaging, page => Url.Action("SearchPaging", "Participant", new { page = page, pageSize = ViewBag.PageSize, order = ViewBag.CurrentSort }),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions
    {
    DisplayLinkToIndividualPages = true,
    DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false,
    LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
    PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "dvBody",
    }))
</div>
```

It works fine...

What I need is to add a Javascript validation before calling the Url Method. Depend on the result of the validation, the Url has to be executed or not.

What I did is adding

```
  $(document).on("click", "#contentPager a", function (event) {
     alert(1);
  });
```

This function is called when I click the paging... But I do not know if it possible to prevent the calling to the Url method... it is always executed

I have tried using

```
$(document).on("click", "#contentPager a", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Without any result..

It is possible to prevent it?

Thanks